# Object constructed within reference initialization

Tags: c++, reference

Hopefully a simple question: Given a class

```
class Foo {
 // some private data members
 public : 
    Foo(int) {...};
}
```

What happens if an instance is constructed during reference initialization?

```
const Foo &f(Foo(1));
```

Does `f` now refer to a dead object - and if not, will the object get destructed correctly when `f` goes out of scope?

And, does anything change if we make the reference initialization use a expression?

```
const Foo &f( condition? Foo(1) : Foo(42));
```

Comment: Non-`const` references can't be bound to temporaries...

Comment: @Brian - Sorry - forgot the const! Just added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an rvalue reference or a const reference is initialized with a prvalue of class type, the lifetime of the temporary object is extended to the lifetime of the reference. So no worries about dangling references.

Comment: For the conditional statement, it is being destructed twice(or destructor being called twice), once on creation and the other on going out of scope. What is happening there?

Comment: That's because `condition? Foo(1) : Foo(42)` is another temporary that is copy-constructed from one of the other temporaries.

Comment: gotcha, I am tracking.

Comment: @FredOverflow so if `Foo` is derived from `boost::noncopyable`, will it work?

Comment: @Roddy It does not work according to the standard and clang, but g++ does not complain.